# Rails using helper method in form_tag select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a view in my Rails app where I'm wanting to select a unit to dispatch to a call.  Here is what it currently looks like.

```
   <%= form_tag dispatch_call_call_path(call), :class => "dispatch-form-tag" do  %>
   <%= select_tag(:unit_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(Unit.active.order("unit_name ASC"), "id", "unit_name"), :include_blank => true, :required => true, :class => 'select' )%>
   <%= button_tag 'Dispatch', class: 'btn btn-danger btn-small', data: {disable_with: "<i class='icon-spinner'></i>Processing..."} %>
   <% end %>
```

This works fine and dandy but I want to display more information about the unit in the dropdown such as whether or not they are on a call and their status.

I wrote this helper under calls_helper

```
def unit_select
   Unit.active.order("unit_name").map{|unit| unit.calls.where(call_status: "open").empty? ? ["#{unit.unit_name} #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] : ["#{unit.unit_name} (on call) #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] }
 end
```

Which when used in a form gives me Unit name (on call) Unit type if the unit is on a call.

When I am creating a new call from scratch this is how I use it in the form.

```
      <%= f.select(:unit_ids, unit_select,  {}, {:multiple => true, :class => 'select'}) %>
```

I want to use this same helper in my index view so when a unit is dispatched to a call the user sees the same information that they would when they are creating a call.

But I'm not sure how to use my unit_select helper in a select_tag.  I've read the API docs for Rails but can't seem to figure this one out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried 'options_for_select(@units{ |u| [u.status, u.id] })' and define @units using the helper method.

Comment: Thanks, just tried this and getting syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')'.  Here's what my line looks like `       <%= select_tag :unit_ids, options_for_select(@units{ |u| [u.status, u.id] }), :include_blank => true, :required => true, :class => 'select' %>
`

Comment: How about  options_for_select(@units.collect { |u| [u.status, u.id] })      basically add a collect call to units

Comment: I am getting the exception: undefined method status for ["CST01 (on call) CCT", 34]:Array  And I've instantiated Units in my calls controller like this in the index action     @units = Unit.active.order("unit_name").map{|unit| unit.calls.where(call_status: "open").empty? ? ["#{unit.unit_name} #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] : ["#{unit.unit_name} (on call) #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] }

Comment: When I try it in the terminal I get an array of arrays: like this [["CST01 (on call) CCT", 34], ["DFWPR1 BLS", 39], ["M1 CCT", 1], ["M10 CCT", 7]] based off this line  @units = Unit.active.order("unit_name").map{|unit| unit.calls.where(call_status: "open").empty? ? ["#{unit.unit_name} #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] : ["#{unit.unit_name} (on call) #{unit.unit_type.unit_type}", unit.id] }

Comment: maybe then try the simpler:  options_for_select(@units, "id", "status)

Comment: Here's what worked: <%= select_tag :unit_ids, options_for_select(@units, "id"), :include_blank => true, :required => true, :class => 'select' %>